# Photoshop script to export unique layer permutation compositions

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm using the following [script](https://github.com/mechanicious/photoshopCompositionComposer) to generate compositions within the top-level document groups. However I want only unique combinations of the layers and not every possible combination.

For example there are 5 elements in 5 colours and I want only unique combinations to be generated, as shown in the screen shot. There should be a total of 120 unique compositions, 24 with a blue background, 24 with a yellow background etc.

[image]

The script that's being used is as follows.

```js
var userDisplayDialogsPref = app.displayDialogs;

app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL;

var savePath;

app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

function getType(thing) {
  if (thing === null) return "[object Null]"; // special case
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(thing);
}

function getCombinations(arr, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        ret.push([arr[i][j]]);
      }
    }
    return ret;
  } else {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var elem = arr.shift();
      for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
        var childperm = getCombinations(arr.slice(), n - 1);
        for (var k = 0; k < childperm.length; k++) {
          ret.push([elem[j]].concat(childperm[k]));
        }
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
}

function showAllArtLayers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < layerSets.length; i++) {
    for (var z = 0; z < layerSets[i].artLayers.length; z++) {
      layerSets[i].artLayers[z].visible = true;
    }
  }
}

function hideAllArtLayers() {
  var layerSets = app.activeDocument.layerSets;

  for (var i = 0; i < layerSets.length; i++) {
    if (layerSets[i].artLayers.length) {
      for (var z = 0; z < layerSets[i].artLayers.length; z++) {
        layerSets[i].artLayers[z].visible = false;
      }
    } else {
      for (var z = 0; z < layerSets[i].layerSets.length; z++) {
        layerSets[i].layerSets[z].visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function getArtLayerCollectionCollection() {
  var layerSets = app.activeDocument.layerSets,
    artLayerCollectionCollection = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < layerSets.length; i++) {
    var artlayerCollection = [];
    if (layerSets[i].artLayers.length) {
      for (var z = 0; z < layerSets[i].artLayers.length; z++) {
        if (layerSets[i].name.indexOf('__') !== 0)
          artlayerCollection.push(layerSets[i].artLayers[z]);
      }
    } else {
      for (var z = 0; z < layerSets[i].layerSets.length; z++) {
        if (layerSets[i].name.indexOf('__') !== 0)
          artlayerCollection.push(layerSets[i].layerSets[z]);
      }
    }
    artLayerCollectionCollection.push(artlayerCollection);
  }

  return artLayerCollectionCollection;
}

function combine() {
  var artLayerCollectionCollection = getArtLayerCollectionCollection(),
    artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations = getCombinations(artLayerCollectionCollection, getLayerSetsCount()),
    continueConfirmation;

  if (!artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations.length) return alert('Script has aborted. No combinations found. Please make sure no empty groups are present.');

  continueConfirmation = confirm(artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations.length + " combinations found. Would you like to continue?");

  if (!continueConfirmation) return alert('Script has been aborted.');

  savePath = Folder.selectDialog("Select an output folder");

  var includePSDFiles = confirm('Would you like to include corresponding PSD documents?')

  for (var i = 0; i < artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations.length; i++) {
    hideAllArtLayers();
    var artLayerNames = [];
    for (var z = 0; z < artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations[i].length; z++) {
      var artLayer = artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations[i][z];
      artLayer.visible = true;
      artLayerNames.push(artLayer.parent.name);
      artLayerNames.push(artLayer.name);
    }
    saveDocumentAsPNG(savePath + '/' + normalizeSaveFileName(artLayerNames.join('')).substr(0, 254));
    if (includePSDFiles) saveDocumentAsPSD(savePath + '/' + normalizeSaveFileName(artLayer.parent.name + artLayerNames.join('')).substr(0, 254));
  }
}

function getSmallestLayerSetCount() {
  var count = null,
    layerSets = app.activeDocument.layerSets;

  for (var i = 0; i < layerSets.length; i++) {
    var artLayers = layerSets[i].artLayers;

    if (count === null) count = artLayers.length;

    if (artLayers.length < count) count = artLayers.length;
  }

  return 1;
}

function getLayerSetsCount() {
  var layerSets = app.activeDocument.layerSets,
    count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < layerSets.length; i++) {
    if (layerSets[i].name.indexOf('__') !== 0) count++;
  }

  return count;
}

function normalizeSaveFileName(name) {
  return name;
}

function saveDocumentAsPNG(path) {
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(new File(path), new PNGSaveOptions());
}

function saveDocumentAsPSD(path) {
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(new File(path), new PhotoshopSaveOptions());
}

combine();

app.displayDialogs = userDisplayDialogsPref;
```

The logic would have to be for example: if the background is "blue" then don't use any layer named blue in the other group layers AND not to use the same colour in other group layers, all the layers in all the groups have the colour prefixed, as in "blue hills" or "red sun".

I'm not sure how to go about modifying the above script to achieve the intended result.

---

In Photoshop the PSD has the following grouping for example.

**-Hills (Group)**

--Pink hills

--Blue hills

--Yellow hills

--Violet hills

--Green hills

**-Sun (Group)**

--Pink sun

--Blue sun

--Yellow sun

--Violet sun

--Green sun

**-Sky (Group)**

--Pink sky

--Blue sky

--Yellow sky

--Violet sky

--Green sky

**-Trees (Group)**

--Pink trees

--Blue trees

--Yellow trees

--Violet trees

--Green trees

**-Background (Group)**

--Pink background

--Blue background

--Yellow background

--Violet background

--Green background

So if the "--Pink background" layer from the group "Background" is used THEN "--Pink sun" from the group " "Sun", "--Pink hills" from the group "Hills" "--Pink trees" from the group " "Trees", "--Pink sky" from the group " "Sky" cannot be used.

AND

Same colours cannot be used in the other groups, example,

If background layer used is blue and hills are violet then the sun, trees and sky cannot be violet, they have to be of other colours.

This is the [PSD file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBICFgEyKDBLU8ENnFUP6swbCCIDem7Y/view?usp=sharing) being used.

Comment: Does your image list all possible values for each column?

Comment: Also, you'd be better to list those values in text. And, unless you need help with he Photoshop-side of things, then that isn't needed here.

Comment: @LeeTaylor thanks, I've updated the question with an example. I assume the permutations in the original post would be taken care of by the script based on the logic I've outlined.

Comment: Please list the values for `Trees` and `Sky`, also.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @LeeTaylor thanks, where do I add your code in the main script?

Comment: See my comment on my answer...

Answer (score 0):

1. We first declare our array of groups and their allowed colours
2. We recursively add an (initially) empty list, to our function adding available colours from each group, until we run out of groups
3. We then check that each colour in the array is unique, if so we add to the `combinations` array.
4. Remove the line with `**` if you don't want the group name included in the result.

```js
var groups = // define our groups.
[
  { name : "background", items :
  [ 
    "Pink", "Blue", "Yellow", "Violet", "Green"
  ]},
  { name : "trees", items :
  [
    "Pink", "Blue", "Yellow", "Violet", "Green"
  ]},
  { name : "hills", items : 
  [
    "Pink", "Blue", "Yellow", "Violet", "Green"
  ]},
  
  { name : "sky", items :
  [
    "Pink", "Blue", "Yellow", "Violet", "Green"
  ]},
  
  { name : "sun", items :
  [
    "Pink", "Blue", "Yellow", "Violet", "Green"
  ]}
];

var combinations = []; // This will store all valid combinations

// Determine if any value in the array is a duplicate
function hasDuplicates(arr) 
{
    var counts = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) 
    {
        if (counts[arr[i]] === undefined) 
        {
            counts[arr[i]] = 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Recursively add on the combination to the remaining parts of the groups
var processGroups = function(combination, groups)
{
  if(groups.length === 0) // end of the line, check for duplicates in this combination
  {
    if(!hasDuplicates(combination) )
      combinations.push(combination);
    return;
  }
    
  var remainder = groups.slice(); // Clone groups
  var first = remainder.shift();  // Remove the first item and store in first

  for(let colour of first.items)
  {
    let result = [].concat(combination);
    result.push("**" + first.name + "**"); // Remove this line if you don't want the group name included in the result
    result.push(colour);
    processGroups(result, remainder);
  }
}

processGroups([], groups);

console.log("All combinations are listed below:");
console.log(combinations);
```

Comment: The above would eventually replace `artLayerCollectionCollectionCombinations = getCombinations(artLayerCollectionCollection, getLayerSetsCount()),` but I will need to see what that returns in your existing code. Can you update your question to include a sample of what that data returns?

Comment: If I run the code you provided it gives this error. Error 25. unexpected - Line: 65
->    for(let colour of first.items).

If I run the code I posted in my question it says the number of combinations found and if to continue. (it shows all the possible combinations of group layers including same colour layers.)

Comment: Hence, I said **eventually**. I need to know more about your data, and how it works in PS. It may be that PS doesn't like modern JS syntax. Which version of PS are you using?

Comment: I'm using PS 22.3.0 on a mac. I'll post a link with the PSD.

Comment: Have added the PSD file being used in the question.

Comment: No worries. I will have a look this evening.